# Unable to customize the box to short single line in 'boxplot' type Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, boxplot

I am able to narrow down `box` to single line in `boxplot` type Highcharts. However, I need to make that single line to shorter than lines at the end as below image.[image]

Code for `series` is:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Observations',
  data: [
      [760, 848, 848, 848, 965],
      [733, 939, 939, 939, 1080],
      [714, 817, 817, 817, 918],
      [724, 806, 806, 806, 950],
      [834, 864, 864, 864, 910]
  ],
  tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/83TM7/)**

Am I missing any setting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to do? Not sure what is meant by "I need to make that single line to shorter than lines at the end".  Perhaps whiskerLength is what you're talking about?  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.boxplot.whiskerLength  Also, perhaps the error bar type would better suit your needs...?  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.errorbar

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible, but you can wrap drawPoints function of boxplot, and develop the this part of code:

```
if (doQuartiles) {
                crispCorr = (pointAttr['stroke-width'] % 2) / 2;
                crispX = mathFloor(crispX) + crispCorr;
                q1Plot = mathFloor(q1Plot) + crispCorr;
                q3Plot = mathFloor(q3Plot) + crispCorr;
                left += crispCorr;
                right += crispCorr;
                boxPath = [
                    'M',
                    left, q3Plot,
                    'L',
                    left, q1Plot,
                    'L',
                    right, q1Plot,
                    'L',
                    right, q3Plot,
                    'L',
                    left, q3Plot,
                    'z'
                ];
            }
```

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this documentation. It really helps me to think in other ways :)